# Saving a Queue to a File

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file-io, queue

My goal is to have a text file that allows me to append data to the end and retrieve and remove the first data entry from the file. Essentially I want to use a text file as a queue (first in, first out). I thought of two ways to accomplish this, but I am unsure which way is more Pythonic and efficient. The first way is to use the json library.

```
import json

def add_to_queue(item):
    q = retrieve_queue()
    q.append(item)
    write_to_queue(q)


def pop_from_queue():
    q = retrieve_queue()
    write_to_queue(q[1:])
    return q[0]


def write_to_queue(data):
    with open('queue.txt', 'w') as file_pointer:
        json.dump(data, file_pointer)


def retrieve_queue():
    try:
        with open('queue.txt', 'r') as file_pointer:
            return json.load(file_pointer)
    except (IOError, ValueError):
        return []
```

Seems pretty clean, but it requires serialization/deserialization of all of the json data every time I write/read, even though I only need the first item in the list.

The second option is to call `readlines()` and `writelines()` to retrieve and to store the data in the text file.

```
def add_to_queue(item):
    with open('queue.txt', 'a') as file_pointer:
        file_pointer.write(item + '\n')


def pop_from_queue():
    with open('queue.txt', 'r+') as file_pointer:
        lines = file_pointer.readlines()
        file_pointer.seek(0)
        file_pointer.truncate()
        file_pointer.writelines(lines[1:])
        return lines[0].strip()
```

Both of them work fine, so my question is: what is the recommended way to implement a "text file queue"? Is using json "better" (more Pythonic/faster/more memory efficient) than reading and writing to the file myself? Both of these solutions seem rather complicated based on the simplicity of the problem; am I missing a more obvious way to do this?

Comment: When do you need the text file? For example, could you implement a context manager class that holds the queue in memory during runtime then saves it to a file on `__exit__`?

Comment: The script is being run by a cronjob. It only needs to read from the queue once per execution. When the queue is exhausted, it calls a function to get more data and then stores that in the queue. In actuality I don't think I'd ever need to add one item at a time to the queue (however I included it in my question for completeness).